# MouseEnterUp' is not valid. 'MouseEnter' is not an event on 'System.Windows.Trigger'

Tags: wpf

I've got WPF window(WPF browser app) with 3 rectangles. I want to set trigger on one of the rectangles. But When I write in XAML

```
 <Rectangle Height="17" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="rectangle1" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="278" >
        <Rectangle.Triggers>
            <Trigger Mouse.MouseEnter="MouseEnterUp"/>
        </Rectangle.Triggers>
    </Rectangle>
```

and define MouseEnterUp as

```
    public void MouseEnterUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Window2 x = new Window2();
        x.Show();
    }
```

I've got such error

'MouseEnterUp' is not valid. 'MouseEnter' is not an event on 'System.Windows.Trigger'.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how [`Triggers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Trigger.aspx) work... but anyway, you don't need a trigger for this:

```
<Rectangle Height="17" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="rectangle1" Stroke="Black"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="278"
        Mouse.MouseEnter="MouseEnterUp">
</Rectangle>
```